# Images doesn't load in <GallerySwiper> function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on this app and I'm using this function called  which I installed -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gallery-swiper. **Github** -> https://github.com/Luehang/react-native-gallery-swiper.

The thing is if I loaded this screen directly it loads the images well but if I navigate to this page from another page then these images are not being loaded.

This is the code inside my **app.js**.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './src/home/home'; 
import ddsScreen from './src/household/dds';

const navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  dds: {
    screen: ddsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: 'Buy Dish Drainer Standard'
    }
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home', 
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    title: 'HOME',
  }
});

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

now say that I change '**initialRouteName**' to 'dds', it'll work. The  is used inside dds component. I want the images to load as I navigate through screens and finally reach the dds screen.

Comment: Share your Gallery screen code!

Comment: @DevAS https://github.com/Luehang/react-native-gallery-swiper/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: Really? I want to share your code not the lib

Comment: @DevAS <GallerySwiper
                                images={[
                                    { source: require('../imgs/1.jpg'), dimensions: { width: 300, height: 250}},
                                    { source: require('../imgs/2.jpg'), dimensions: { width: 300, height: 250}}
                                ]}
                                style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
                            />